# Cannot access xampp htdocs folder from another PC over same network, but can access phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have xampp installed on my PC. I can access xampp dashboard and PHPmyadmin by entering 192.168.x.x on another computer over same network. But when I type in **192.168.x.x/folder_name/** where folder_name is folder in htdocs it redirects to **localhost/foder_name** hence showing object not found error.

What is reason that it is redirecting to my ip to localhost on that computer?

Comment: Can you post the meaningful portion of your httpd.conf (or httpd-vhosts.conf, whichever is relevant)? There could be an absent, or misconfigured Alias.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi 
I dont know what could be meaningful portion so I have pasted the file on this link.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cz2rbWXIEy4xMggixXIAkpd63bgTPc0CySyRtIq1f6s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Fair enough. That file shows httpd-vhosts.conf is enabled. Please add a link onto it as well, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you @FabienHaddadi . Please see the vhosts.conf at link below:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uzVCy3UsO6ss0bA_YNfr2WaF1LL5woeI6US9RxyvAsU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: All right, your VH file is all commented out anyway, so there's nothing down this end. Now, back to your main file, I can see your ServerName is set to localhost, so you should call your page http://localhost/FolderName/ anyway. When you say "object not found error", what error do you actually get? Any numeric HTTP error code too?

Comment: See when I type my IP on another computer on same network, lets say _192.168.1.x/phpmyadmin_, it works absolutely fine. But when I access any folder inside htdocs like _192.168.1.x/mywebsite_ then it automatically gets redirected to _localhost/mywebsite_ and results in blank page.
So the question is why is it taking localhost rather than taking my IP in address bar.

Comment: Is your physical phpmyadmin folder inside C:/xampp/htdocs? Also, when you say "blank page", can you see an HTTP error code in the title bar or in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

1. check your  firewall for any input  with incoming on port 80  ( or  for  the test  turn off firewall )
2. in xampp look  for  http.conf  (configuraton file  for apache)

look for  something like that : 
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1

remove "deny from all"  and reload apache

Comment: 1. Turned off my firewall already.
2. I have pasted my http.conf file in comments above. I cannot find the line in it. Here it is : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cz2rbWXIEy4xMggixXIAkpd63bgTPc0CySyRtIq1f6s/edit?usp=sharing